# scroll div content with hidden scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a `div` with some content that should scroll in the x direction like the image **but** I want its ***scrollbar to be hidden*** here is my code
I also try commented ways in the code below but didn't work.

[image]

```
<style>
 main{
   width:500px
 }
 .company{
   /* overflow-x: scroll; */
   width:800px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   display: flex;
   gap: 12px;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 16px;
 }
 /*.scrollable-company::-webkit-scrollbar{
   display: none;
 } */

</style>
<main>
<section class="company">
  <button class="btn-company active">All</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Nike</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Adidas</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Asics</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Reebok</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">New Ba..</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Converse</button>
</section>
</main>
```

Comment: Did you try **overflow-x: none;**?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll). You should find a solution to your problem there

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code:

```
  .company {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
  .company::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
```

That's also the answer to the same question here: [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

```css
 main{
   width:300px;
 }
 .company{
   /* overflow-x: scroll; */
   width:300px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   display: flex;
   gap: 12px;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-size: 16px;
 }
 
  .company {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
  }
  .company::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
```

```html
<main>
<section class="company">
  <button class="btn-company active">All</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Nike</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Adidas</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Asics</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Reebok</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">New Ba..</button>
  <button class="btn-company ">Converse</button>
</section>
</main>
```